# Google Maps URL Schema for multi stops

Tags: ios, google-maps, url-scheme

I would like to open Google Maps app on iOS using the url scheme for showing directions with multiple stops.

The web url for testing is:

```
https://google.com/maps/dir//49.54643774,22.28223445/49.54679476,22.28170513/49.54726735,22.28154318/49.54760869,22.28156607/49.54820312,22.2815506/49.54856556,22.28146425/49.54907329,22.28133231/49.54989807,22.28207924/49.55017454,22.2824851/49.55064392,22.28306989/49.5508548,22.28325003/49.55143275,22.28381447/49.55169439,22.28410868/49.5520271,22.28443534
```

I tried many configurations of the app scheme using `comgooglemaps://` without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme#display_directions) for opening the app.

To simplify it, this is the format you need to follow:

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=Google,+1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043&daddr=Google+Inc,+345+Spear+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&center=37.422185,-122.083898&zoom=10
```

in swift you would do something like this, take note of the callback option, you can choose to not have it if you don't want to return to your app:

```
let testURL = URL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(testURL) {
  let directionsRequest = "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" +
    "?daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York" +
    "&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp"

  let directionsURL = URL(string: directionsRequest)!
  UIApplication.shared.openURL(directionsURL)
} else {
  NSLog("Can't use comgooglemaps-x-callback:// on this device.")
}
```

Edit: To use coordinates, use it this way:

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=52.3668563,4.8890813&daddr=52.357516,4.902319&zoom=10
```

Edit 2: For for more points on the map append coordinate using `+to:Latitude,Longtitude` to the `daddr` parameter

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=52.3668563,4.8890813&daddr=52.357516,4.902319+to:52.357786,4.891913&zoom=10
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't actually figure it out exactly. In the example you have provided, you use names separated by comma, and I need to provide list of coordinates like 49.55169439,22.28410868 49.5520271,22.28443534. I can't fint what form should URL have for this.

Comment: @DamianDudycz try out the coordinate based sample!

Comment: That won't do, I have 14 of these, so I can't just set start and end.

Comment: @DamianDudycz i have added info on how to show more points. I think you should pay more attention to the documentations!

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you for help. I couldn't find info about "+to:" before

Comment: Thank you very much. I added a waypoint using code you wrote. THANKS!

Comment: i got solution for android device with url_launcher https://stackoverflow.com/a/59143783/5374771